# Alembic's server_default and Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I would like to run a migration using alembic from a sqlalchemy model to another.
The initial model looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy_utils import UUIDType

class Foo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = db.Column(UUIDType(binary=True), primary_key=True)
    foo_field = db.Column(JSONB)
```

and I want to make `foo_field` not nullable:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = db.Column(UUIDType(binary=True), primary_key=True)
    foo_field = db.Column(JSONB, nullable=False)
```

I want to run an alembic script to alter the column, but since some of my existing `foo_field` are null, I want to use `server_default` to apply a default value (an empty dict) when altering

```
op.alter_column('foo',
         'foo_field',
         existing_type=postgresql.JSONB(astext_type=sa.Text()),
         nullable=False,
         server_default="{}")
```

I tried different options to pass to this `server_default`, such as `text("{}")`, `lambda: {}`, `{}`, `text("SELECT '{}'")`. But it seems to be just ignored and all I get is an `IntegrityError`  when running the upgrade :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) column "foo_field" contains null values [SQL: 'ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN foo_field SET NOT NULL'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

Does a string representing an empty dict is considered as not-null? What should be passed to this `server_default`? Should I fraction the code in multiple steps to fill the default value before setting the field not nullable (not the prefered option, I have a bunch of columns that I want to apply this to)?

I am using postgres 10.5, I [read](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2018/09/20/postgresql-11-a-first-look/) that postgres 11 will kinda handle better this sort of operation, should I switch to it now?

Thanks in advance for help/advices

Comment: You can already add columns with `NOT NULL DEFAULT something` in pg10 and older. In pg11 you still **won't** be able to **alter** columns in such a way, so there is no point in switching.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone comes here again, this is what I use

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.execute("ALTER TABLE {table_name} ALTER COlUMN {column_name} set DEFAULT {new_default_value};")
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.execute("ALTER TABLE {table_name} ALTER COlUMN {column_name} set DEFAULT {old_default_value};")
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [`Rewriter`](https://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/autogenerate.html#fine-grained-autogenerate-generation-with-rewriters) and do so yourself automatically.

override the `ops.AlterColumnOp` operation and return two operations first one being an update column operation with the server default value and the second one is the original `op`.

Comment: That's a good idea, although I think overriding this function would be a bit of a stretch. I decided not to make this column nullable, there was not real reason for it to be absolutely filled with an empty dictionary.